# how to add custom input field in limesurvey

Tags: php, limesurvey

Hi I want to add an autocomplete input field in limesurvey but don't know hot accomplish this task. Any one know where to add code for add custom input field?

in autocomplete.js

```
In this file the code that call a php function on the base of keyup in input field.
```

in checkInDb.php

```
In this file the code check term that come from **autocomplete.js** and search in database then send response back to js file
```

Where to add this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the LimeSurvey documentation it explains very well how to modify the surveys with Javascript. 
You don't explain too much, but I think you can find the solution [here](http://manual.limesurvey.org/Workarounds:_Manipulating_a_survey_at_runtime_using_Javascript#Use_jQuery_Autocomplete_plugin_to_suggest_answers_for_text_inputs").

Comment: Thanks Puce for answer

Comment: Please mark the answer as valid if it helped you find the solution.